# Fancybox multiple links to same gallery without duplication

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

So I have a gallery of images, and a few links to it. Something like that

```
<a href="/images/1.jpg" rel="1">title</a>
<a href="/images/1.jpg" rel="1">link to first image</a>
<a href="/images/2.jpg" rel="1">link to second image</a>
<a href="/images/3.jpg" rel="1">link to third image</a>
```

This is cause first image to duplicate in fancybox. Like this:
http://filebeam.com/2dec41a1820f2525f040424578c4421c.jpg

How can I make a multiple links to the same object without duplications?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all links are visible and clickable, then you could create a custom click handler for the first one that opens fancyBox gallery from the rest -

```
<a data-trigger-rel="gallery" class="fancybox-trigger" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<br />
<br />

<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

$(".fancybox-trigger").click(function() {

    $("a[rel='" + $(this).data('trigger-rel') + "']").eq(0).trigger('click');

    return false;

});


$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

​

See in action - http://jsfiddle.net/g9R4H/

Comment: FYI, fancybox v3 has `trigger element` feature, simply use `data-fancybox-trigger` attribute with the value of fancybox group name - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/VGoRqO?editors=1010